# Interaction between Illustrator and PDF

Tags: javascript, pdf, automation, scripting, adobe-illustrator

- I wanted to create script that will save as current document into pdf and when that's pdf is opened it that script should put signature block within that pdf. I was able to create scripts for both but I don't know how can I combine both the codes and run them in sequential order.

  Script for Illustrator-

  ```
  saveFileToPDF();
  function saveFileToPDF() {
    var doc = app.activeDocument;

    if (app.documents.length > 0) {
       var docName = doc.name;
      var extensionIndex = docName.lastIndexOf(".");
      var fileName = (extensionIndex > -1) ? docName.slice(0, extensionIndex) : docName;
      var saveName = new File(doc.path + "/" + fileName + ".pdf");
      var saveOpts = new PDFSaveOptions();

      saveOpts.compatibility = PDFCompatibility.ACROBAT5;
      saveOpts.preserveEditability = true;

      doc.saveAs(saveName, saveOpts);
    }
  }
  ```

  Script for Acrobat Pro-

  ```
  var name = "sigField";
  var type = "signature";
  var page = 0;
  var mySigRect = [3016,247,3138,189];
  var sf = this.addField(name, type, page, mySigRect);
  this.saveAs(this.path);
  this.closeDoc();
  ```

  And below is the combined script, but this one is only creating and saving PDF file not putting signature field in it.

  ```
  saveFileToPDF();

  function saveFileToPDF() {
    var doc = app.activeDocument;

    if (app.documents.length > 0) {
      var docName = doc.name;
      var extensionIndex = docName.lastIndexOf(".");
      var fileName = (extensionIndex > -1) ? docName.slice(0, extensionIndex) : docName;
      var saveName = new File(doc.path + "/" + fileName + ".pdf");

      var saveOptions = new PDFSaveOptions();
      saveOptions.preserveEditability = true;

      doc.saveAs(saveName, saveOptions);

      // Call the function to run code in Adobe Acrobat
      runCodeInAcrobat(saveName);
    }
  }

  // Code for Adobe Acrobat
  function runCodeInAcrobat(filePath) {
    var bt = new BridgeTalk();
    bt.target = "acrobat";
    bt.body = 'var avDoc = app.openDoc("' + filePath + '");' +
              'var pdDoc = avDoc.getNthPDDoc(0);' +
              'var page = pdDoc.getPageNumWords(0);' +
              'var rect = [100, 100, 200, 200];' + // Adjust signature field position and size
              'var annot = pdDoc.addAnnot({ type: "Widget", subtype: "Sig", rect: rect });' +
              'annot.userName = "John Doe";' +
              'annot.pageNum = 0;' +
              'annot.AP = annot.getAppearance();' +
              'annot.AP.setRect(rect);' +
              'pdDoc.flattenPages(0, 0);' +
              'pdDoc.save(0, "");' +
              'pdDoc.closeDoc();' +
              'app.execMenuItem("Quit");';  // Quit Adobe Acrobat Pro after performing actions

    bt.onResult = function(result) {
      if (result === "executed") {
        alert("Actions completed in Adobe Acrobat Pro.");
      } else {
        alert("Failed to execute actions in Adobe Acrobat Pro.");
      }
    };

    bt.send();
  }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically this code should work if you're lucky:

```
saveFileToPDF();

function saveFileToPDF() {
  var doc = app.activeDocument;

  if (app.documents.length > 0) {
    var docName = doc.name;
    var extensionIndex = docName.lastIndexOf(".");
    var fileName = (extensionIndex > -1) ? docName.slice(0, extensionIndex) : docName;
    var saveName = new File(doc.path + "/" + fileName + ".pdf");

    var saveOptions = new PDFSaveOptions();
    saveOptions.preserveEditability = true;

    doc.saveAs(saveName, saveOptions);
    doc.close(); // just in case

    runCodeInAcrobat(saveName.fsName);
  }
}

// Code for Adobe Acrobat
function runCodeInAcrobat(filePath) {
  var bt = new BridgeTalk();
  bt.target = "acrobat";
  bt.body = sign.toString() + ';\r sign("' + filePath + '");';
  bt.onError = function(resObj) {
     alert(resObj.body);
     exit();
  }
  bt.send(100);

  function sign(path) {
    var doc = app.openDoc(path);
    var name = "sigField";
    var type = "signature";
    var page = 0;
    var mySigRect = [16,247,138,189];
    var sf = doc.addField(name, type, page, mySigRect);
    doc.saveAs(doc.path);
    doc.closeDoc(true);
  }
}
```

The same way I can run Photoshop from InDesign and Illustrator, etc. I'm pretty sure it should work to some degree. There is no problem in the code. But it gives me this error:

[image]

Which means that I can't run Acrobat via Bridgetalk at all.

You can try to google the phrase **bridgetalk "target could not be launched"**. Not that it gives me to much answers, though. As far as I can tell the problem is somewhere in the system settings and versions of adobe products, beyond the code.